# Controlling terra SpatRaster size in memory

Tags: r, terra

Here I create a simple raster that only contains the integer "1".

```
r <- rast(matrix(rep(1, 100), nrow = 10))
```

This object does not have a datatype associated with it:

```
datatype(r.in.flt)
# ""
```

I write it to disk using `datatype = "FLT4S"` and then read it back in.

```
name.flt <- "test_FLT4S.tif"
writeRaster(r, name.flt, datatype = "FLT4S")
r.in.flt <- rast(name.flt)
```

I also write it to disk using `datatype = "INT1U"` and then read it back in.

```
name.int <- "test_INT1U.tif"
writeRaster(r, name.int, datatype = "INT1U")
r.in.int <- rast(name.int)
```

The incoming datatypes appear correctly:

```
datatype(r.in.flt)
# "FLT4S"
datatype(r.in.int)
# "INT1U"
```

And the corresponding file sizes show a correct reduction in size for the integer datatype:

```
file.size(name.flt)
# 665
file.size(name.int)
# 618
```

But in memory, the two objects appear to have the same size:

```
object.size(r.in.flt)
# 1304 bytes
object.size(r.in.int)
# 1304 bytes
```

**QUESTIONS:**

1. Why does the original SpatRaster `r` not have a datatype associated with it?
2. Is it possible to set to set the datatype of the SpatRaster `r`? How? I want to do this to make sure that the SpatRaster I'm working with is saved as an integer datatype so that it takes up the least amount of memory as I process a large dataset.
3. Why does the object that was read in from the "INT1U" file not consume **less memory** in R?

Comment: The obect.size test is in effect the 'path to file' object, file.size('test.FLT8S.tif')
[1] 3266, datatype(r1) [1] "FLT8S", dim(r1) [1] 100  10   1, object.size(r1) 1304 bytes, as rasters not loaded into memory except meta data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data type is only relevant to raster files. The object itself does not have one. Raster values that are in RAM are always numeric (double precision; 8 bytes). But note that methods like `as.data.frame` and `extract` return the type that is on disk.

See `terra::mem_info` for RAM requirements.

The main design principle of terra is that you do not have to read all values into memory. The data are automatically processed in smaller chunks if that is necessary. There may be exceptions, and I do not know your application so I cannot be sure, but you may be needlessly complicating things.

Comment: I am running into issues with disk space on my computer while running a loop on over 120 layers in a raster stack. My available disk space goes down from 100GB to 0bytes before finishing my loop. I was wondering if it would help to convert my float raster into integer. However this answer suggests that it would not make a difference.

Comment: The solution is probably to write the rasters to disk